# Show that of Turing decidable languages is closed under concatenation.

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines

The question and its answer is found in the following picture:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I could not understand:
1- why we scan the input tape from left to right until a blank is encountered?

2- Also I could not understand why exactly one tape symbol receives a mark?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "why"? We're describing an algorithm. If we chose to mark more than exactly one tape symbol, it would be a different algorithm.

Comment: I mean that if I were to prove that they are closed under star, there is an algorithm that say that any number of cells can be marked in that case ..... so why in case of closure under star its different from closure under concatenation? @MishaLavrov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be languages. A string $w$ is in the concatenation of $A$ and $B$ if you can write it as $w= ab$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  This means that you can split $w$ into two halves. The first half is a string from $A$ and the second half is a string from $B$.

If you have two decideable languages $A$ and $B$, you can make a decider for $A$ concatenated with $B$ as follows:

Given a two-tape nondeterministic Turing machine,

1. Nondeterministically guess where to split the string into two parts $w=ab$.
2. Run the first machine to make sure the first half is in $A$. If it isn't, reject.
3. Run the second machine to make sure the second half is in $B$. If it isn't, reject.
4. If the string really is in the concatenation of $A$ and $B$, then one of these guesses will be correct; that nondeterministic branch will accept, so the computation itself accepts.

Everything else is just bookkeeping:

- "Read until you encounter a blank space" just means "Read the input until you reach the end of the input".
- "Mark just one of the symbols." This is a way to mark where you think the division $w=ab$ is.
- So, altogether these two instructions are: "Read each of the input characters, and nondeterministically decide where to divide the input into two parts by putting a mark where the division should happen."